# How to determine if a SMB Client has established a Signed SMB communication from my Windows Server 2012?

Tags: windows-server-2012, network-share, server-message-block

Is there a way to find from my Windows 2012 Server if the client has established a [signed communication](http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2010/12/01/the-basics-of-smb-signing-covering-both-smb1-and-smb2.aspx) ?

[Net Session](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490711.aspx) gives the basic details but does not say anything about signing.

```
C:\>net session \\a.b.c.d
User name       Administrator
Computer        a.b.c.d
Guest logon     No
Client type
Sess time       00:08:02
Idle time       00:07:50

Share name     Type     # Opens

--------------------------------------
test           Disk     0
The command completed successfully.
```

Is there any [Powershell cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635726.aspx) or any administrative tool or command that would provide with such information ? Thanks in advance.

Edit 1:
I also tried the following. [Get-SmbConnection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635713.aspx) should be executed on the client to find the Servers to which the client has establish connections.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator> Get-SmbConnection | Select-Object -Property *
ContinuouslyAvailable : False
Credential            : domain\administrator
Dialect               : 3.00
Encrypted             : False
NumOpens              : 3
ServerName            : server1
ShareName             : test
UserName              : SERVER1\Administrator
PSComputerName        :
CimClass              : ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/SMB:MSFT_SmbConnection
CimInstanceProperties : {ContinuouslyAvailable, Credential, Dialect, Encrypted...}
CimSystemProperties   : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties
```

Comment: This is a great question. Although, I suspect the only answer (currently) is to watch the connection as it is negotiated in Wireshark/Netmon.

Comment: Not tested myself so i am not sure, but you could give a try to [Get-SmbConnection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635713.aspx) Powershell cmdlet

Comment: @krisFR. I did try Get-SmbConnection and it does not provide such information.

Answer (score 5):

As of the time of this writing, the only way to really know this for sure is to watch the network connection as it's being negotiated through Wireshark or Network Monitor.

Right now, nothing exposes this data through an API, WMI class, etc.

The `Get-SMBConnection` Powershell cmdlet *will* get you this information in the future, but not today.

The cmdlet is simply a wrapper around the `MSFT_SmbConnection` WMI class.

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'Root\Microsoft\Windows\SMB' MSFT_SmbConnection
```

Returns the exact same info. If you go read [the MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830461(v=vs.85).aspx) for that WMI class, you will see that the documentation lists a `Signed` property in addition to the `Encrypted` property that you see today.

```
class MSFT_SmbConnection
{
  string  ServerName;
  string  ShareName;
  string  UserName;
  uint32  SmbInstance;
  string  Credential;
  uint64  NumOpens;
  string  Dialect;
  boolean ContinuouslyAvailable;
  boolean Encrypted;
  boolean EnableLoadBalanceScaleOut;
  boolean Signed;  // ^_^ *trollface*
};
```

The documentation then goes on to say:

> Signed
>
> Data type: Boolean
>
> Access type: Read-only
>
> TBD. (To be determined)
>
> Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012, Windows 8: 
>   This property is not supported before Windows Server Technical Preview
>   and Windows 10 Technical Preview.

Windows 10 preview is when it first shows up. So there you have it.

Answer (score 2):

For the benefit of Google, I was also struggling with discovering if my SMB Signing was actually working or not.
I swear Get-SmbConnection wasn't returning 'Signed' property yesterday, but today when I run (on my Windows 10 1903 x64 machine PSVersion 5.1.18362.145):

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-SmbConnection | fl *
SmbInstance           : Default
ContinuouslyAvailable : False
Credential            : DOMAIN\user
Dialect               : 3.0.2
Encrypted             : False
NumOpens              : 1
Redirected            : False
ServerName            : server.domain
ShareName             : share
Signed                : False
UserName              : DOMAIN\user
PSComputerName        :
CimClass              : ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/SMB:MSFT_SmbConnection
CimInstanceProperties : {ContinuouslyAvailable, Credential, Dialect, Encrypted...}
CimSystemProperties   : Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.CimSystemProperties
```

'Signed' is a property returned, and shows True or False.

However on my Server 2012 R2 PSVersion 5.1.14409.1018 currently does not.
Colleague on Windows 10 1809 PSVersion 5.1.17763.592 also has it.

Comment: this works for me, on windows 10, must open powershell in win10 as **run as administrator** for the `Get-SmbConnection` command to work otherwise you will get access denied.

Comment: as of 2021 on window 10, this `Get-SmbConnection | fl *` in powershell {run as administrator} works; I can get Encrypted=True however not able to get Signed=True; on RHEL 7.9 with samba 4.10; https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/668955/getting-signed-samba-connection-to-win10

Comment: Strange. On my Windows 10 Pro 21H1 x64 19043.1165, I do get it.
Granted all my current connections are to Windows SMB v3.0.2.